# Type annotation required on overloaded literals when passed to printf

Tags: haskell, printf, type-inference

I'm confused with these:

When I write like this

```
main = do
    putStrLn . printf "%f" $ 2.3
```

It will cause

> No instance for `(PrintfArg a0)` arising from a use of `printf`
>
> The type variable `a0` is ambiguous

The code works well in GHCi, this error happened when I use `runhaskell` in a terminal.

So I write

```
putStrLn . printf "%f" $ (2.3 :: Double)
```

It's Ok, but I don't know the reason.

Don't `"%f"` infer `2.3` belongs to type `Double`?

As far I know, `putStrLn` has the type `String -> IO()`, can't `printf`'s result be converted to `String` when `2.3` is not decorated by `Double`?

Answer (score 5):

Because Haskell is not a dependently typed language, the **value** of `printf`'s first argument (i.e. `"%f"` in your case) has no way of prescribing the **type** of `printf`'s second argument (`2.3` in your case).

On its own, `2.3`'s type is `Fractional a => a` because it is an [overloaded literal](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html). [`printf`'s type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) might look a bit magic, in that it is very polymorphic so that e.g. `printf "%s" "foo"` and `printf "%f" 2.3` can both typecheck. This is achieved via the [`PrintfType`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#t:PrintfType) and [`PrintfArg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#t:PrintfArg) typeclasses.

All in all, in `printf "%f" 2.3`, the type checker only knows that `2.3` is some type `a` that has both a `Fractional` and a `PrintfArg` instance; but it doesn't know what `a` actually needs to be. And it needs one type so that the `Fractional` and `PrintfArg` instances can be resolved.

This situation is somewhat similar to the [`show . read`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486494/477476) problem, and your example works in GHCi because of `Num` [defaulting](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) to `Double`.

Comment: It should be noted that if you turn on `-Wall`, the compiler will warn you when defaulting occurs in a (possible very complex) expression, so that code where defaulting is applicable will no longer "magically" work only sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can I think it as that every variable should be prescribed with a concrete type when haskell itself can't infer a concrete type( just infer some typeclass constraint).

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have the type of the variable "escaping" the definition, then it's OK to have leftover constraints; e.g. `foo x = (show x, show x)` is perfectly valid and type-able at `(Show a) => a -> (String, String)`, since the type variable `a` occurs in its type, and so it can be "someone else's problem".